# How do I can customise every app icon using java?

Tags: android, launcher

I want to customize my android device with custom icons for every app. I have downloaded whicons, but they don't cover all apps, so Now I want to make my own icons for the apps that whicons doesn't cover in android studio. In conclusion I want to make app that can change other apps icons.

I haven't done anything yet, because I'm like new in java programming. I don't know much about android api.